# How to stop a permalink redirecting to a page whit same slug but different permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, pages

I have this CPT that has this permalink

http://example.com/area-cliente/colecciones/basicos/

and this other page

http://example.com/basicos/

And going to http://example.com/area-cliente/colecciones/basicos/ redirects me to http://example.com/basicos/ for some weird reason, can anyone help me?

EDIT1: By the way i have "'has_archive'           => false," in cpt code in functions.php

EDIT2: As a test i changed the slug for http://example.com/basicos/ to http://example.com/basicos-2/ to test what happened and now http://example.com/area-cliente/colecciones/basicos/ does not redirect to nothing but a 404 page, and the cpt page is published and public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i think i solved it for myself, i still have a problem but is unrelated to this question so i might make a new question for that one.

The problem was that what i had registered as the slug for the CPT was "area-cliente/%category%" when i removed the "/%category%" and added the %category% thing in the permalink menu whit the plugin "Custom Post Type Permalinks" it now works, it solves this question but leaves me whit another problem.

TL;DR: don't put in the slug of a CPT %category% because it appears to not work

Answer (score 0):

Go to WordPress Settings, and re-save permalinks.

Comment: aleardy did that, doesn't work for me, but thanks :)

Comment: I think i solved it by myself, it was my error for doing some weird thing like putting %category% in the slug of the cpt configuration on functions.php :)